# php form send empty data online but works fine on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, emptydatatext

i got some forms in php so i can upload data into a mysql database, i already do the trials on a localhost server with xampp, but when i upload my files into my host ftp the forms doesnt work,so, i was thinking it has something to do with the fact that i put this file and the "connect.php" one too under password restriction, and that has something to do with the file permissions too but i already grant permission to the user of the database and permission to the file and i also had tried without the password protected thing, and nothing, always had the same result, so i start to experiment a little and i figured out that the image uploads fine into the database but nothing else did it, knowing that i try to "echo out" the other input results but non of it show something, and i came into the conclusion that my form is sending empty data, SOMEONE CAN TELLME IF IM RIGHT?, WHY THIS IS HAPPENING! PLEASE HELP ,heres my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider_upload">

<h1>Slider principal</h1>
    <div class="forma">

    <form action="sliderPrincipal.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p><label for="encabezado">Encabezado</label>
        <input type="text" id="encabezado" name="encabezado" /></p><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
        <p><label for="fileupload">File to upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" /></p><br>
        <p><label for="articulo">Articulo</label>
        <textarea id="articulo" name="articulo" rows="26" style="width: 100%;" >Escribir aqui</textarea></p><br>
         <button type="submit" name="submit" value"send">Upload File</button>
    </form><br><br>

</div>
</div>

<div class="message">
    <?php 



$file_dir = "../uploaded";

if (isset($_POST['encabezado'])){
$encabezado = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['encabezado']);
$articulo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articulo']);
}


foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array){
   //echo "path: ".$file_array['tmp_name']."<br />\n";
   //echo "name: ".$file_array['name']."<br/>\n";
   //echo "type: ".$file_array['type']."<br/>\n";
   //echo "size: ".$file_array['size']."<br/><br/>\n";
   //echo "encabezado ".$encabezado;

        if(is_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'])){
        move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], "$file_dir/".$file_array['name']) or die ("Your image couldnt be uploaded <br>");   
        $newpath = addslashes("uploaded/".$file_array['name']);
        include "connect.php"; 
        $addfile = "INSERT INTO slider (encabezado, image, articulo) VALUES ('$encabezado','$newpath', '$articulo')"; 
        $result = mysql_query($addfile);
        if ( $result === FALSE ) {
            echo "your post could not be uploaded but we already got your image in our files ";
        } else{
            echo '<p style="padding: 20px;"><h1>Your post was successfully uploaded <h2></p><br><br>';

        }


        mysql_close();  

    } else "No file found";


 }

 ?>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the error too please

Comment: have you got your db on server and updated the connection file

Comment: You also need to incude your db config file as said by @NaveenThally

Comment: Hey @Utkarsh there's no error, even the succeeded echo is displayed, and, ya, my connection file is set to connect with the server database, and i think is working fine cause as i say before, the image path is successfully uploaded into the server data base

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly

Comment: Check whether the database is connecting using die then check whether your image is getting uploaded then echo your query and check

Comment: @Utkarsh the problem is the text that comes from the input "encabezado" and "articulo" isn't received by the $_POST method and send empty data to the database, then the col "encabezado" and "articulo" ends empty in my database

Comment: @NaveenThally i think thats exactly what im doing, the connect file is successfully working and send no error, even the picture path gets uploaded to the database, but nothing else do it, not the "encabezado" input nor the "articulo" input :/

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_dir = "../uploaded";
if($_REQUEST['submit']) {
    $encabezado = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['encabezado']);
    $articulo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['articulo']);
    foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array){
        if(is_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'])){
            move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], "$file_dir/".$file_array['name']) or die ("Your image couldnt be uploaded <br>");   
            $newpath = addslashes("uploaded/".$file_array['name']);
            include "connect.php"; 
            $addfile = "INSERT INTO slider (`encabezado`, `image`, `articulo`) VALUES ('$encabezado','$newpath', '$articulo')"; 
            $result = mysql_query($addfile);
            if ( $result === FALSE ) {
                echo "your post could not be uploaded but we already got your image in our files ";
            } else{
                echo '<p style="padding: 20px;"><h1>Your post was successfully uploaded <h2></p><br><br>';

            }
        mysql_close();  

        } else "No file found";


 }
}
```

Try above code.

Note: not tested.

Comment: hey @Vijayakumar Selvaraj i try it but nothing  happened, not even a success or failure message, thanks for trying anyway